# why does my nodejs program run differently with --inspect-brk option

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, dbus

I've got a simple nodejs program that tries to connect to NetworkManager via DBus using dbus-network-manager. Unfortunately, I can't use chrome://inspect to debug it because it behaves differently in the debugger.

Here's the code:

```
const NetWorkManager = require('dbus-network-manager').connect()
.then(nm => {
    // this branch taken when run with or without --inspect option
    console.log ('connected successfully');
})
.catch(err => {
    // this branch taken when node launched with --inspect-brk option
    console.log ('failed to connect, error was: ' + err);
})
```

And here's how it runs in 3 different scenarios:

```
$ node app.js
DBus test app running in development mode connected successfully

node --inspect app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/3fcf6bd4-f6fa-4bf2-8dcd-30c8fdcd14b8
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
DBus test app running in development mode
connected successfully

node --inspect-brk app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e935e8b4-0d78-4ad0-a5c1-894e5631c8fa
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
DBus test app running in development mode
failed to connect, error was: Error: No introspectable
```

I can work around the problem given that it seems to run ok with `--inspect`, but I'd love to know why this is happening at all.

Thanks!